# Batman Equation

Tags: plotting, style

I am trying to plot out the batman symbol in mathematica. I have the basic equations but I am having some difficulty with plottingstyles and connecting the two ears with a straight line. I was wondering if I can specifically make one graph darker than the other in mathematica and I would like to have the middle of the symbol greyed out.

Any help will be appreciated[image]

```
   Plot[{ y = -3 Sqrt[64 - x^2] (UnitStep[x + 10] - UnitStep[x + 2]),
  y = 3 Sqrt[64 - x^2] (UnitStep[x - 10] - UnitStep[x - 2]),
  y = (-25 (x + 1) - 10) (UnitStep[x + 2] - UnitStep[x + 1]),
  y = (-25 (x - 1) + 10) (UnitStep[x - 2] - UnitStep[x - 1]),
  y = (-.5 (.9 x + 17.54)^2) (UnitStep[x + 17.5] - UnitStep[x + 8]),
  y = ( -.6 (1.1 x + 7.5)^2 - 52) (UnitStep[x + 8] - UnitStep[x]),
  y = (-.5 (-.9 x + 17.54)^2) (UnitStep[-x + 17.5] - UnitStep[-x + 8]),
  y = ( -.6 (-1.1 x + 7.5)^2 - 52) (UnitStep[-x + 8] - UnitStep[-x]),
  y = 5;
   }, {x, -20, 20}, PlotRange -> {-100, 100}, PlotStyle -> {Black}, 
  PlotStyle -> Axis, Filling -> Top, FillingStyle -> Opacity[.2], 
  Mesh -> None]
```

Comment: Your bottom piece can be expressed entirely in terms of `Piecewise[]`: `Piecewise[{{-.5 (.9 x + 17.54)^2, -17.5 <= x < -8}, {-.6 (1.1 x + 7.5)^2 - 52, -8 < x <= 0}, {-.6 (-1.1 x + 7.5)^2 - 52, 0 < x <= 8}, {-.5 (-.9 x + 17.54)^2, 8 < x <= 17.5}}]`. Try something similar for the top.

Comment: that's actually a very good idea. I never really used piecewise functions. I will have to take a look into it

Comment: @user3709772: Did you see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54506/is-this-batman-equation-for-real , https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dnzfajfpym

Answer (score 9):

I like this version of the Batman curve, since it can be drawn as two piecewise functions (i.e. the top and bottom wouldn't be double-valued anywhere). This appears to get what you were going for,

```
Plot[{
  Piecewise[{
    {Null, x < -19.5},
    {0, -19.5 <= x < -8},
    {-3 Sqrt[64 - x^2], -8 <= x < -2},
    {(-25 (x + 1) - 10) , -2 <= x < -1},
    {0, -1 <= x < 1},
    {(25 (x - 1) - 10) , 1 <= x < 2},
    {-3 Sqrt[64 - x^2], 2 <= x < 8},
    {0, 8 <= x < 19.5},
    {Null, x > 19.5}}],
  Piecewise[{
    {Null, x < -19.5},
    {-.5 (.9 x + 17.54)^2, -19.5 <= x < -8},
    {-.6 (1.1 x + 7.5)^2 - 52, -8 < x <= 0},
    {-.6 (-1.1 x + 7.5)^2 - 52, 0 < x <= 8},
    {-.5 (-.9 x + 17.54)^2, 8 < x <= 19.5},
    {Null, x > 19.5}}]
  }, {x, -20, 20}, 
 PlotRange -> {-100, 100},
 Mesh -> None,
 PlotStyle -> Black,
 Filling -> {2 -> {{1}, {{Opacity[0.2], Black}, None}}},
 Exclusions -> None]
```

[image]

I would personally tweak the ears and the top of the head just a bit,

```
Plot[{
  Piecewise[{
    {Null, x < -19.5},
    {0, -19.5 <= x < -8},
    {-3 Sqrt[64 - x^2], -8 <= x < -2},
    {(-15 (x + 1) - 10) , -2 <= x < -1},
    {-(x^2 - 1) - 8, -1 <= x < 1},
    {(15 (x - 1) - 10) , 1 <= x < 2},
    {-3 Sqrt[64 - x^2], 2 <= x < 8},
    {0, 8 <= x < 19.5},
    {Null, x > 19.5}}],
  Piecewise[{
    {Null, x < -19.5},
    {-.5 (.9 x + 17.54)^2, -19.5 <= x < -8},
    {-.6 (1.1 x + 7.5)^2 - 52, -8 < x <= 0},
    {-.6 (-1.1 x + 7.5)^2 - 52, 0 < x <= 8},
    {-.5 (-.9 x + 17.54)^2, 8 < x <= 19.5},
    {Null, x > 19.5}}]
  }, {x, -20, 20}, 
 Axes -> False,
   Mesh -> None,
 PlotStyle -> Black,
 Filling -> {2 -> {{1}, {{Black}, None}}},
 Exclusions -> None, 
 AspectRatio -> .35, 
 ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Comment: `Null` is certainly shorter, but `Indeterminate` is the usual way to handle off-domain evaluations.

Comment: I like to think outside the box  :-D  Also, it appears I forgot to set the bound for the upper curve.

Comment: @J.M. - Just for no real reason, how hard would it be to automate the process of generating the piecewise function?  Can you think of a way to automatically split up the line segments from, say, `EdgeDetect["http://i.stack.imgur.com/dqJry.png" // Import]`?  If so, then we could fit each segment to a polynomial.

Comment: not having sufficient image processing expertise, I can't answer that. But that sounds like a question that should be asked separately. ;)

Comment: @J.M. thanks!! what is the purpose of using Null again?

Answer (score 4):

From [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BatmanCurve.html):

```
Plot[{With[{
w = 3*Sqrt[1 - (x/7)^2], 
l = (6/7)*Sqrt[10] + (3 + x)/2 - (3/7)*Sqrt[10]* Sqrt[4 - (x + 1)^2], 
h = (1/2)*(3*(Abs[x - 1/2] + Abs[x + 1/2] + 6) - 11*(Abs[x - 3/4] + Abs[x + 3/4])), 
r = (6/7)*Sqrt[10] + (3 - x)/2 - (3/7)*Sqrt[10]* Sqrt[4 - (x - 1)^2]}, 
    w + (l - w)*UnitStep[x + 3] + (h - l)*UnitStep[x + 1] 
    + (r - h)*UnitStep[x - 1] + (w - r)*UnitStep[x - 3]], 
    (1/2)*(3*Sqrt[1 - (x/7)^2] + Sqrt[1 - (Abs[Abs[x] - 2] - 1)^2] 
    + Abs[x/2] - ((3*Sqrt[33] - 7)/112)*x^2 - 3)*((x + 4)/Abs[x + 4] 
    - (x - 4)/Abs[x - 4]) - 3*Sqrt[1 - (x/7)^2]}, 
{x, -7, 7}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Black, Axes -> False, Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]

And as a region plot:

```
bm[{x_, y_}] = WolframAlpha["batman insignia",    
{{"DefiningInequalitiesPod:Lamina", 1}, "ComputableData"}][[1]];

RegionPlot[Evaluate[bm[{x, y}]], {x, -8, 8}, {y, -4, 4}, 
PlotPoints -> 150, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

As J.M. pointed out below, this is a different curve, but Iwill leave it up incase useful. If not, please leave a comment below & I will remove.

Comment: 1. That's a different curve. 2. Did you happen to notice the references?

Comment: @J.M. Ah, no - just saw batman curve and typed away without thinking ! Will leave it posted for the moment, but will remove if not helpful;.

Answer (score 0):

So, a way to plot several functions all with wildly varying options is to `Show[$PLOT1, $PLOT2, $PLOT3]`.

Something you can do is just write a function to plot on a range, like you did here, but do each one is a separate `Plot[]`. Then, you can use `Show` to put them all on one graph, and each `Plot` has almost completely separately configurable display options.